# Java JComponents being cut off near edge of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

I have recently begun working with JComponents to create GUI systems. Everything is working but the bottom and right sides of the JFrame do not get painted over and remain white.

Screenshot of running GUI:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVGzr.png]

In the screenshot you can see the 'drknBtn' is displayed correctly; this is because I hovered over it with the mouse before taking the picture. Hovering over the buttons refreshes them and they appear as normal. Due to this, I would assume the panel that holds them, 'bottomPnl' is covering that white space, but that panels background is not showing at the bottom portion. Any ideas on what could cause this? I have tried calling 'bottomPnl.repaint()' directly before calling pack(), but no change.

My code is below.
Note: For each JComponent, I created a class extending that component. This way I could set default values for the components in the constructors of these classes instead of doing each one individually. I'll list the relevant properties of the Frame and Panels.
Frame: setSize(width,height); setResizeable(false); setLocationRelativeTo(null);
Panel: setLayoutManager(from contructor); setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height)); same for setMinimumSize and setMaximumSize.

```
public Display(String title, int w, int h){

    width=w;
    height=h;
    frame = new FrameUI(title,w,h);

    //parent panel
    parentPnl= new PanelUI(width,height, new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,0,0));
    parentPnl.setBackground(new Color(100,175,175));

    //top panel
    topPnl= new PanelUI(width,(int)(height*.15), new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,0,0));
    topPnl.setBackground(new Color(100,175,175));

    chooseFileBtn = new ButtonUI("Browse...",topPnl.getWidth()/4,(int)(topPnl.getHeight()*.9),new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            fc = new FileChooserUI();
            fc.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Image files", ImageIO.getReaderFileSuffixes()));
            int result = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
            try {
                if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    picture.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(fc.getSelectedFile()).getScaledInstance(picture.getWidth(),picture.getHeight(), 0)));
                }
            } catch (Exception iOException) {
            }
        }

    });

    //middle panel
    midPnl= new PanelUI((int)(width*.85),(int)(height*.7), new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,0,0));
    midPnl.setBackground(new Color(75,125,125));

    picture = new LabelUI("",midPnl.getWidth(),midPnl.getHeight());
    picture.setBackground(new Color(75,125,125));
    picture.setVisible(true);
    picture.setOpaque(true);
    picture.setIcon(null);

    //bottom panel
    bottomPnl= new PanelUI(width,(int)(height*.15), new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,0,0));
    bottomPnl.setBackground(new Color(100,175,175));

    ltnBtn = new ButtonUI("Lighten Picture",bottomPnl.getWidth()/3,(int)(bottomPnl.getHeight()*.9),new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    });
    ltnBtn.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    ltnBtn.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

    drknBtn = new ButtonUI("Darken Picture",bottomPnl.getWidth()/3,(int)(bottomPnl.getHeight()*.9),new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    });
    drknBtn.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    drknBtn.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    //add UI Objects
    topPnl.add(chooseFileBtn);

    midPnl.add(picture);

    bottomPnl.add(ltnBtn);
    bottomPnl.add(drknBtn);

    parentPnl.add(topPnl);
    parentPnl.add(midPnl);
    parentPnl.add(bottomPnl);

    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();     
    contentPane.add(parentPnl);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: My first guess is you're using `null` layouts, my second guess is you've overridden `paint` or `paintComponent` and failed to call their `super` methods

Answer (score 1):

```
topPnl= new PanelUI(width,(int)(height*.15), new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,0,0));
```

looks to me like you are manually trying to control the size of the panels and therefore the size of the components added to your panels. Your calculations are wrong and some components aren't displayed properly. Also all your sizes are fixed at creation time and will not adjust if the size of the frame ever changes.

Don't try to control the sizes manually. Use layout managers to dynamically size components based on the properties of the component.

I fail to see why you would want a button to be 15% of the space available to the frame.

If you want the button to be larger than normal you can set extra empty space around the text of the button by using:

```
button.setMargin( new Insets(50, 50, 50, 50) );
```

Then just add the button to a panel using a FlowLayout and let the layout manager do its job.

The default layout for a frame is a `BorderLayout`, so you can then add the "topPnl" to the frame using:

```
frame.add(topPnl, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

The other panels can then be added using:

```
frame.add(midPnl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.add(bottomPnl, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

This is how Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more information and examples.

The main point is use methods like `setMargin(...)`, to provide hints to the component on what their preferred size should be.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by removing the 'setSize()' method in the FrameUI constructor. However, I still do not understand how you could dynamically size panels as you said while still maintaining the proportions I want for them. Thank you @camickr for the pointers, my original problem is fixed. I'll look into more javadocs and tutorials on layout managers and such.